# How tofilter out empty entries when creating a pie chart?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

When I create pie chart in Kibana and use `Split Slices` by `Term` called `DataType`, is it possible to filter out all cases when `DataType` is `""`. Unfortunately, if I go to Filters menu in the top of a chart, I can see only the non-empty values of `DataType`.
The filter `does exist` neither helps, because `DataType` always exists, just in some cases it is equal to `""` instead of, e.g. `DT1`, `DT2`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [exist](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) query, search for "mapping", then you will see that you can define the null value, you can define that null value is empty string, then in exist query it's will filter out

Comment: Could you please put an example with a screenshot or some link? Thanks.